# sound not working on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, sound

Ubuntu 11.10

My speakers have stopped working - no sound is coming out. I tested speakers on my friends windows machine and they're working fine. I'm not sure of what to post, please help me guide of how get the sound back.

any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Call `alsamixer` from the terminal and look whether the output is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Install "Gnome Alsa Mixer" from the software Center and try adjusting the volume labels though it.

Comment: I installed alsa mixer, but no sound is coming. I tried adjusting all controls, but left in vain :-(

Comment: How to check my hardware (sound card) is enabled or any issue with it?